# No suitable constructor found for java

Tags: java

I am getting the error message "no suitable constructor found" when the constructor I am trying to use only has one `int` parameter.  When I try to create a new instance in another class with one `int` parameter, it is giving me that error. What am I doing incorrectly to cause this error?

```
public class dHeap <T extends Comparable <? super T>> implements dHeapInterface<T> {
  
    private int children;
    private T[] array;
    private int size;
  
    public dHeap (int heapSize){
       array = (T[]) new Comparable[heapSize];
       children = 2;
       size = 0;
    }
    public dHeap (int d, int heapSize) { 
       array = (T[]) new Comparable[heapSize];
       children = d;
       size = 0;
    }
...
}

public class MyPriorityQueue<T extends Comparable <? super T>> extends dHeap<T> {
  private dHeap<T> queue;
  private int size;
  
  public MyPriorityQueue(int queueSize)
  {
    queue = new dHeap<T>(queueSize);
    size = 0;
  }
...
}
```

the error is

```
no suitable constructor found for dHeap()
constructor dHeap.dHeap(int,int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
constructor dHeap.dHeap(int) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

Comment: How are you craeting the object of MyPriorityQueue? Please include the Error Stack.

Comment: You need to provide a constructor with an int argument to `dHeap` in order to instantiate it.

Comment: isnt that what i did? the first contructor in dheap has an int argument for it

Comment: Why are you extending `dHeap` and also including an instance of `dHeap` in `MyPriorityQueue`? Did you want `MyPriorityQueue` to have two `dHeap` instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `MyPriorityQueue` **extends** `dHeap`, and `dHeap` doesn't have a no-arg constructor, you *must* call an appropriate constructor using `super( ... args here ... )`.

Since `MyPriorityQueue` **is** a `dHeap`, you'll likely want to remove field `queue`, and replace `queue = new dHeap<T>(queueSize);` with `super(queueSize)`.

You'll also likely want to remove field `size`.

Comment: i did not know i had to use super(..) when extending a different class, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @NongShimmy You might want to read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

In your code for class dHeap you have not created any default constructor
however in MyPriorityQueue you are extending it and ever constructor calls its super default constructor which is not present in this case..